# Assets compression in Rails 6 with Webpack not working

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I changed my config/webpack/production.js to:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()

module.exports.plugins.push(
    new CompressionPlugin({
        asset: "[path].gz[query]",
        algorithm: "gzip",
        test: /\.(js|css)$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
    })
);
```

But this did not compress anything in my assets.
Am I adding the plugin in the wrong way or missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what part of webpacker minified my code, but the problem was that I was running webpack manually but not in production mode, this ignored anything related to compression.
I added to my config/webpack/production.js:

```
module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()

module.exports.optimization = {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: new UglifyJsPlugin({
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        sourceMap: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
            compress: {},
            mangle: true,
        }
    })
}
```

That alone did not solve the issue, only after I added the production mode flag, the compression started happening:

```
bin/webpack  --mode production
```